# Print Preview Is Blank After adding External Stylesheet reference in print html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to print DIV content of a page.What i do is retrieve contents of the div using JS and pass it to new window obj on which i call .print().
THe Text contents and images are displayed as such.
Just when i add this line to retrieved div contents

```
<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

the print preview is blank. I tried adding other stylesheets as well,same result. Whatever style sheet reference i add to print html contents,same result -blank preview page.
here is My JS code to print page contents.

```
var printDivCSS = new String ('<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
function Popup(htmldata) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('test', 'eChallanReceipt', 'height=800,width=800,top=20;left=20');
    var str ="<html><head><title>test</title>"; 
    str+= "</head><body>"+ printDivCSS + htmldata+"</body></html>";
     mywindow.document.write(str);
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return false;
}
```

Please suggest some fix. I want to style the print content.
Browser: Chrome

The same code is working in Mozilla. But in Chrome i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for anyone who is having this problem now here is the solution.

It is showing blank page because the document is not finished loading yet. so to fix it add `mywindow.print()` in a `timeout` .

```
var printDivCSS = new String ('<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
function Popup(htmldata) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('test', 'eChallanReceipt', 'height=800,width=800,top=20;left=20');
    var str ="<html><head><title>test</title>"; 
    str+= "</head><body>"+ printDivCSS + htmldata+"</body></html>";
     mywindow.document.write(str);
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    $( mywindow.document).ready(function(){
  //set this timeout longer if you have many resources to load
    setTimeout(function(){
       mywindow.focus();
       mywindow.print();
    },1000);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The page renders blank as  the css has not finished loading

Comment: however i've used window.onload function instead of setTimeout...since it cannot be reliably said if the css will be able to load in the given timeout

Comment: Is there not a better way? The timeout is a bit hacky and if it takes longer to load the stylesheet then it will break and print a blank page

Answer (score 0):

CSS should be called from the head of the page, not the body.

Comment: I have tried adding css in the head also,still doesn't work

Comment: Hard to tell without a live example. I see the issue is Chrome only. Could you check the developer tools? (Rightclick -> inspect). You will be interested in the network tab (enable preserve log) and the resources tab (open the "frames" folder) to check if the stylesheet is loaded correctly. Also refer to the console, see if there are any errors there. Additionally you could use the elements tab to see what is going on the the HTML data. Another suggestion, add in 'media="print"' in your css link